# Checkbox NSButton inside NSPopover changes colors when running

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton, nspopover

I'm getting a strange behavior of checkboxes inside NSPopover on OS X 10.10.3.

Colors of checkboxes are distorted but other elements like regular buttons or labels have correct colors.

Top image: how NSPopover renders in a running app (black background is from another app).

Bottom image: NSPopover view in Interface Builder.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Effect Views (like used in NSPopover) are totally messed up in OS X Yosemite. Luckily they are working fine now in El Capitan.

A workaround on Yosemite should be to set the `appearance` property of each checkbox, label, scrollView etc. to `NSAppearanceNameAqua`

Comment: Thanks! `self.problematicBtn.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameAqua];` fixed it.